# Custom listview help in android

Tags: android, custom-lists

Hi what i want to do is fetch audio songs from sd card and store it in custom listview just to show play list can any one tell me how to write adapter for this custom listview below is my code please help me out in this.

```
class Mp3Filter implements FilenameFilter {
 public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return (name.endsWith(".mp3"));
  }
 }




public class MpActivity extends Activity {
ListView ll;

  private static final String path= new String("/sdcard/music/");
  private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
 @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   ll=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ll);
   ll.setEnabled(true);

 }




    public void playlist(){
File home = new File(path);
    if (home.listFiles( new Mp3Filter()).length > 0) {
    for (File file : home.listFiles( new Mp3Filter())) {
        songs.add(file.getName());
    }

    }
             //Error on this statement
             ll.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<T>(this, R.layout.main, songs));


  }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
ll = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.main,songs);

lv =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.songs_list);

lv.setAdapter(ll);
```

Comment: Here is some code I used to add an array adapter to a textview.

     AutoCompleteTextView textView3 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_classif);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.auto_list_item, CLASSIF);
        textView3.setAdapter(adapter);